# Is it possible to store a QPushButton in a QVariant?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qvariant

I'd like to know if it's possible to store a QPushButton in a QVariant. More precisely, I am trying to use it in a QStandardItemModel with the function `setData`. Here's what I want to do :

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Update");
setData(index(0, 0), "Button");
setData(index(0, 1), button);
```

But obviously, it doesn't work like that so I tried this :

```
QVariant variant;
variant.setValue(button);
setData(index(0, 1), QVariant::fromValue(variant));
```

And it's not working either. I'd like to do it **without using a QTableView** (I know there is a setIndexWidget in this kind of view).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to store pointer to a button in your model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QVariant` needs a metatype for types it can store. Qt provides a set of commonly used types, but you can simply extend it, using the [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) Macro:

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVariant>

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QPushButton*)

void foo() {
    QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton("button");
    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(b1);
    QPushButton *b2 = qvariant_cast<QPushButton*>(v);
}
```

Note: If you want to use your custom metatypes also in queued slot connections or with `QMetaMethod`, you have to call `qRegisterMetaType<QPushButton*>()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Do yo uhave any idea how I could display my button after that? `setData` allows me to display QString and QIcon, but I can't retrieve my button the same way

Comment: That depends on the View you are using, and which role you are using to set the data (your code uses `Qt::EditRole`). I don't think that provided views by Qt will handle a `QPushButton`... have a look at the Qt Model/View guide: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

Comment: Mmh that's what I thought, guess I'll have to take another path... Thanks anyway for the initial answer :)

Comment: @Alexis If all you want is displaying a button for each entry in your view and interacting with it, you should consider to create a delegate for it. You simply can't use the model's data to pass an object to get it displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, to store it into a `QVariant`:

```
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue((void *) button);
```

and to retrieve it from `QVariant`:

```
new_button_pointer = (QPushButton *) v.value<void *>();
```

Remember to use it with care! It's highly unsafe to handle pointers like this

Comment: Alright for the storage, but how can I display my button after that? Because setData takes `variant` in parameter, but I'd like to have my button :(